# QPushButton in QGraphicsScene requires doubleClick instead of single click

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, signals-slots

I need someone to explain me, when i have qGraphicsScene with

```
void myGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event){
 qDebug()<<event->scenePos();
}
```

and I have qPushButton in the qGraphicsScene with

```
myGraphicsScene::myGraphicsScene(){
QPushButton* pushButton = new QPushButton();
addWidget(pushButton);
connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(doSomething()))
}
```

When I click the button:

- `qDebug` shows me the position.
- The connect is ignored.

When I doubleclick the button:

- `qDebug` shows me the position
- "The thread 0x15b4 has exited with code 0(0x0)"
- `doSomething()` function will be fired.

Can anybody explain me the semantics? Thanks.

Comment: This is because your `mousePressEvent` is consumed by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mousePressEvent in the Qt documentation :

> The default implementation depends on the state of the scene. If there
>   is a mouse grabber item, then the event is sent to the mouse grabber.
>   Otherwise, it is forwarded to the topmost visible item that accepts
>   mouse events at the scene position from the event, and that item
>   promptly becomes the mouse grabber item.

So if you reimplement it like you have done in your code, the event is no longer sent to the mouse grabber (your button) but when you double click, this event is not catched by mousePressEvent (but normally by mouseDoubleClickEvent) and the button is activated only one because the first mouse press is ignored to detect if it is simple click or double click.

hope this will help you.

---

Update : to sove your problem just change your mouseMoveEvent to :

```
void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event){
    qDebug()<<event->scenePos();
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

But I advise you to subclass QGraphicsView and to overload his method mousePressEvent.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Sure. Now it is clear for me now. What solution do you suggest, if I want to know position of clicked cursor onto scene and normal single button click functional?

Comment: I updated my answer. don't forget to mark your question as solved.